# jQuery Ajax response are not asynchronous

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two Ajax calls in my MVC code, for both I have set `async: true`, but however after first request is made and if I try to make 2nd Ajax request, the 2nd is waiting first to get response, only after getting first Ajax response, 2nd request's result is appended. I am not finding solution for this.

Code is as below:

First call:

```
var page_request = $j.ajax({
    url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',
    async:true,
    dataType:"html",beforeSend: function () {
        middlePanel.html('Loading...');
    },
    success: function(data){
        middlePanel.html(data);                     
        fitBoundsWithoutSeco();                        
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        middlePanel.html(textStatus);
    }
});
```

The second is same as first.

Comment: **A** synchronous **J** avascript **A** nd **X** ML should be asynchronous by default.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your second request (or it's relation to first one), can you post it? Also show us how you're executing both requests.

Comment: You server need time to respond especially for heavy database request

Comment: Post the full code please

Comment: Does the second call gets executed if you, for example, comment the first one?

Comment: Can you post the second AJAX call rather than just saying it's the same? Could you also provide some context for where and how these calls are being made?

Answer (score 0):

simultaneous requests in web browsers are limited to 6. any chance you are hitting this limit after your first ajax call? (due to other requests from your page)